# Can I use css3 in my Birt Report?

Tags: eclipse, css, report, birt

I want to use CSS3 in my Birt Report. But its showing the problem of CSS2.

```
  A BIRT exception occurred.
  Plug-in Provider:Eclipse BIRT Project
  Plug-in Name:BIRT Model
  Plug-in ID:org.eclipse.birt.report.model
  Version:4.3.1.v201308301349
  Error Code:Error.StyleSheetException.SYNTAX_ERROR
  Error Message:There are some syntax errors inconsistent with CSS2.
```

So can anyone help me like how can I use my CSS3 file for my report. Is there any plugin or some steps then please let me know.

Comment: You can use css3 in html format only, by including the css file at runtime. But it would be ignored by pdf & other formats

Comment: @Dominique How to include css3 at runtime ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css3 in html format only, by including the css file at viewtime. But it would be ignored by pdf & other formats.

[image]

For example, we are going to include this jquery-mobile theme at viewtime:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.css
```

[image]

To test this example, add a BIRT text element in the report, set type to HTML and include fragment below:

```
<button data-icon="star" data-theme="a" data-form="ui-btn-up-a" class=" ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-icon-star ui-btn-icon-left ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Button</button>
```

Run the report, you will see a great jqueryMobile-like css3 button!

Answer (score 0):

You can also load the external files in the clientScripts of the report using head.js. For example, in a report's clientScripts > clientInitialize event, add:

```
head.js("http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js",
"http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css");
```

In the XML source, this appears as the last line in the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.23" id="1">
<property name="createdBy">Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 4.4.0.v20150206-1039 Build &lt;4.2.3.v20150206-1039></property>
<property name="units">in</property>
<method name="clientInitialize"><![CDATA[head.js("http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js", "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css");
]]></method>
```